# $G$ be a finite group such that for any subgroup $H,K$ of $G$ , $HK$ is also a subgroup of $G$ , then is every subgroup of $G$ normal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a  finite group such that $HK=KH$ for any subgroups $H,K$ of $G$ . Then is every subgroup of $G$ normal ?

[Edit]
(to anyone thinking this question is not worth keeping: Here is the response from the OP to a comment from Tobias Kildetoft stating that the condition implies uniqueness of all Sylow subgroups, and hence that $G$ is nilpotent, JL)

If for a fixed prime $p$, $H,K$ are two different Sylow-p subgroups then $|H \cap K| < |H|=|K|$ and then the subgroup $HK$ is a $p$-subgroup with order $|H||K|/|H \cap K| > |H|$ , impossible ! Hence for a given prime $p$ , there is a unique Sylow-p subgroup . But I have no idea whether these line of arguments passes to all subgroups or not ...

[/Edit]

Comment: $HK=H\times K$?

Comment: @Shuri2060 : I think the definition of $HK$ is pretty common , $HK:=\{hk : h \in H , k\in K\}$ . https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_subgroups

Comment: My bad, didn't know. What have you tried in solving it?

Comment: Do you see that if this is the case then all Sylow subgroups are normal?

Comment: The assumptions of the header and the body of the question seem different.  The Header says $HK$ is a subgroup.  The Body says $HK=KH$ and doesn't say that either form a subgroup.  What did you intend to ask?

Comment: @lulu Those are equivalent.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  Is that obvious?

Comment: @lulu Not trivial, but it is a nice (and fairly common) exercise.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft : Yes I can see that , if for a fixed prime $p$, $H,K$ are two different Sylow-p subgroups then $|H \cap K| < |H|=|K|$ and then the subgroup $HK$ is a $p$-subgroup with order $|H||K|/|H \cap K| > |H|$ , impossible ! Hence for a given prime $p$ , there is a unique Sylow-p subgroup . But I have no idea whether these line of arguments passes to all subgroups or not ...

Comment: @lulu more or less.. $(HK)^2 = H(KH)K = H(HK)K = H^2 K^2 = HK$, and $(hk)^{-1} = k^{-1}h^{-1} \in KH = HK$.

Comment: @Cauchy  Thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, this shows that a group with this property is nilpotent, i.e. the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, so we just need to ask the same question for $p$-groups.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft : ah yes that's true ..

Comment: Are you familiar with the classification of groups all of whose subgroups are normal btw?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft : Um do you mean the classification of all such non-abelian groups which are usually called Hamiltonian groups , each of which is a product of an elementary abelian 2-group , a periodic abelian group with all elements of odd order and the quarternion group ?

Comment: Right, that might make it easier, as it for example changes the question for odd primes to whether this can happen for a non-abelian group (my guess would be no, and one should probably consider a non-central element of order $p$ at some point).

Comment: Actually, here is what looks like the start of an argument: If $H$ is a non-normal subgroup and $x$ is an element of order $p$ that does not normalize $H$ then $H\langle x\rangle$ is not a subgroup since $H$ would have index $p$ in it and thus be normal (i.e. normalized by $x$). So the question is what happens when the non-normalizing elements have larger order.

Comment: No. Groups satisfying this property are sometimes called M-groups, or Iwasawa groups, and they are not necessarily Hamiltonian.  This is discussed in Section 2.3 of the book *Subgroup Lattices of Groups*, by R. Schmidt.  There, he gives the following example, for odd primes $p$:
$$\langle a,x\mid a^{p^3} = 1, x^{p^{3}} = a^{p^{2}}, a^x = a^{1+p}\rangle.$$

Comment: @James I have never seen these called M-groups, as that term usually (in the sort of papers I read) means monomial groups (i.e. groups where all characters are induced from linear characters of subgroups).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm not certain how standard that terminology is.  In this context, it seems to come from the apparently equivalent condition that the lattice of subgroups is modular.

Comment: @James Yeah, that seems to be the case. Thanks for the reference, I would never have found that one myself.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was a little surprised that I could not easily find an example in Robinson's text, since he discusses some of these ideas.  Perhaps there is one there, but none that I could locate quickly.

Comment: What is true is "This question shows no research effort...", ergo, downvote.  What in the heck would six users think it shows such effort?! unless six users happened to think it shows effort, research, etc, etc.

Comment: @amWhy Do you think the material I lifted from the OP's comment demonstrates a satisfactory research effort from their part? We apparently don't agree whether such material is necessary, but that's ok. For my part: if answering a group theory question requires Derek Holt to show up, then it is both sufficiently interesting and sufficiently difficult to be worth keeping. But, I am seeking for a harmonious coexistence of our points of view :-)

Comment: @James I don't know how you feel about it but I would be interested in seeing your example fleshed out as an answer. Not all interested viewers will have access to that book. Your call, of course. No pressure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The group $\langle x,y \mid x^{p^2} = y^p=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{p+1} \rangle$ of order $p^3$ is a counterexample for all odd primes $p$.

The only non-normal subgroups are the $p$ conjugates of $\langle y \rangle$, and the product of any two of these is the subgroup $\langle x^p,y \rangle$.

*Added*: Sorry, I can see now that this example has already been mentioned in comments by James, but it is completely buried in zillions of comments, so it should really be an answer.

Comment: It looks similar, but it's not quite the same example.  Yours is smaller and, it seems, easier to verify has the required properties.